# Array and if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
if([]){}//true
if([]==true){}//false
if([1]==true){}//true
if([2]==true){}//false
if([1,2]==true){}//false
if(['Hi']==true){}//false
if([{aaa:1}]==true){}//false
```

`[ ]` is array. Array is object. Object is true, so `[ ]` is true. This is OK.

But I can't understand other results.

Comment: Agreed - don't expect people to help if you aren't going to follow the SO protocol of ask/answer/accept. (We aren't expecting 100% accept, but 0% is ridiculous)

Comment: An empty array `[]` coerces to the Number value `0` I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([]){}//true
```

All JavaScript objects are truthy - they all coerce to the Boolean value `true`.

---

```
if([]==true){}//false
```

If one Operand is an Object, and the other operand is a Boolean, then both operands coerce to a Number value. An empty array will coerce to `0`:

```
0 == 1 // false
```

---

```
if([1]==true){}//true
```

Same thing here. For an array with one item, that item will coerce to Number and that value will be compared to the other operand:

```
1 == 1 // true
```

---

```
if([2]==true){}//false
```

is:

```
2 == 1 // false
```

---

```
if([1,2]==true){}//false
```

If the array has multiple items, the coercion to Number will result in `NaN`:

```
NaN == 1 // false
```

---

```
if(['Hi']==true){}//false
```

The string coerces to the Number value `NaN`:

```
NaN == 1 // false
```

---

```
if([{aaa:1}]==true){}//false
```

An object also coerces to the Number value `NaN`:

```
NaN == 1 // false
```

Comment: That's good stuff, is there a reference or easy way to test for myself what coercion is happening?

Comment: @Ryley Just read the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3 It says it all right there. The coercion rules are 4. - 9.

Comment: Perfect, I just wanted to make sure that info got attached to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if([]==true){}//false
```

[ ] is not a boolean true it's an array.  That is saying that an empty array IS a boolean true.  It isn't--it's an empty array.

if([]) {}  evaluates it as being defined and not null.

Check this: http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

Comment: That is correct, although it does not explain why `if([1]==true){}//true` . For what I understand, `[1]` is `1` which is `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can find some answers in here:

[Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224)

[JavaScript equality transitivity is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird/5447170#5447170)