# Javascript quirks

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with Chrome's Javascript console recently, and I discovered this oddity:

```
[] == true
false
[0] == true
false
[0] == []
false
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense at first glance (false != false), but I think the real reasoning lies in the polymorphism of the == operator. Comparing an array to a boolean isn't the same thing as comparing an array to another array.

With that said, what are other Javascript quirks you've discovered?

Comment: Haha, of course there's a whole site dedicated to making fun of Javascript.

Comment: Try with `===` and see what happens.

Comment: Open-ended list questions should be avoided, as per the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: [The Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/). It's about quirks.

Comment: In JavaScript, booleans are compared by value and arrays are compared by reference.  So while `[0] == true` is false, `[0] == false` is true, and `[1] == true` is true.  JavaScript is calling `valueOf()` on the array objects.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a [similar question on equality transitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird) recently and Alex provided a really good answer...

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird/5447170#5447170)

I hope that helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 2):

Look into truthy and falsey javascript.  It's seriously called that.