# Is JavaScript's double equals (==) always symmetric?

Tags: javascript, ecma262, comparison-operators, equivalence, symmetric

There are many cases in which JavaScript's type-coercing equality operator is not transitive. For example, see "[JavaScript equality transitivity is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird)."

However, are there any cases in which `==` isn't *symmetric*? That is, where `a == b` is `true` and `b == a` is `false`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Javascript, `==` is always [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation).

The [spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> NOTE 2     The equality operators
>   maintain the following invariants:
>
> - `A != B` is equivalent to `!(A == B)`.
> - `A == B` is equivalent to `B == A`, except in the order of evaluation of
>     `A and  B`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *commutative*?

Comment: @Shtééf: Maybe it should be, but it isn't.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation  Relations aren't operators.

Comment: Thanks for the correction—it's been too long since I picked up that math degree!

Answer (score 37):

It's *supposed* to be symmetric. However, there is an asymmetric case in some versions of IE:

```
window == document; // true
document == window; // false
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Could you specify which versions of IE this occurs in?

Comment: Using IE10 on Win8.0 I see this behavior in "Browser Mode: IE8" (not in IE10, IE9, or *IE7* mode).

Answer (score 11):

The answer to your actual question (is the operator symmetric) is yes. The [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) spec explicitly states:

NOTE 2 The equality operators maintain the following invariants:

- `A != B` is equivalent to `!(A == B)`.
- `A == B` is equivalent to `B == A`, except in the order of evaluation of `A` and `B`.