# PHP Attribute Boolean Oddities

Tags: php, html, boolean

When I echo a PHP Boolean value in HTML, whether inside a tag or outside, the PHP code returned seems to be an empty string for `false` and "1" for `true`. This happens with the Boolean objects, and variables which return Boolean values, but not the strings "true" and "false". For example, in the following code,

```
<div id="<?php echo true; ?>"><?php echo true; ?></div>

<div id="<?php echo false; ?>"><?php echo false; ?></div>
```

the first `div` will have an `ID` of "true" and will have "true" as its text, while the second `div` will have an `ID` of "false" and will have "false" as its content. I have tested this in Google Chrome 34 and Firefox 29 Beta (IE11 won't load the page). I used Firebug, Google Chrome's Web Developer Tools, and Firebug Lite to see what the browser won't show. What's going on here?

Comment: I got confused, do you want it print 'true' and 'false' (as string) or you want to print the value of boolean as true/false?

Comment: I am saying what happens and that I want to know why.

Comment: I don't really care, @Javak, I just want to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is basically converting the boolean value to a string then printing it. The issue is that `false`, when stringified, is the empty string `""`, while `true`is a non-empty string `'1'`.

Why is this odd behavior taking place? The creators of PHP want equality to remain transitive when converting types.

A common design question is: what strings are *truthy* (succeed when compared to `true`) and what strings are *falsy* (succeed when compared to `false`). Many languages consider the empty string `""` to by **falsy** and ***any non-empty string*** to be **truthy**.

From [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), you can see that:

```
(bool) "" == false
(bool) "1" == true
(bool) "0" == true  // this is the important part
(bool) "true" == true
(bool) "false" == true // also of note
```

Its nice to have `((string) false) == false` and `((bool) ((string) false)) == false`.

Other languages, such as JavaScript, [break transitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird) for `==`. Many consider this to be a "bad part" of JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting. Kinda wish they could keep transitivity AND do what the user expects, but we can't have our cake and eat it, too, I guess. Also, showing that `"true" == true` and `"false" == true` might help. (I know these concepts, was just confused by this particular case)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--I updated my post with ``"false" == true``, etc.

Comment: No problem. My original purpose with using "true" and "false" in attributes was essentially to move them from PHP to jQuery during page turnover without AJAX, but then I realized I could just use the strings "true" and "false". I asked this question mainly for academic interest/future reference.