# Check to see if coordinates are in jQuery array using inArray()

Tags: jquery, arrays, coordinates

I'm mapping some points as dots onto a canvas, and I want dots which are repeats to be rendered as larger dots.

I need to check to see if the coordinate has already been mapped before, so I want to store the coordinates in an array as I go.

Here's what I have. I'm unsure about the .inArray line. How do I check to see if the coordinate is already in the array?

```
$(function() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push([0,1]);
  arr.push([2,1]);
  arr.push([3,1]);
  arr.push([4,1]);
  arr.push([5,1]);

  if(jQuery.inArray("2,1",arr)) {
    alert("not there");
  }

});
```

[**HERE'S A SIMPLIFIED FIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/cGheN/1/)

Comment: Does your code work or not work? If it doesn't work, what are the errors or problems that you are encountering?

Comment: How accurate (to how many decimal places) are those coordinates? You might just need to round them off using [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) before pushing them onto your coordinates array.

Comment: It does not work. And I'm pretty sure the coordinates are floating point values. They're coming from Twitter tweet data. It'd be ideal if the coordinates "matched" if they were +/- a few coordinate degrees. I posted a Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `inArray` only tests for simple values (i.e. not arrays or objects).
You can use `filter` instead: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGheN/2/)

```
 var arr = [];
  arr.push([0,1]);
  arr.push([2,1]);
  arr.push([3,1]);
  arr.push([4,1]);
  arr.push([5,1]);

x=2;
y=1;
    var filtered = $(arr).filter(function(){
        thisX = this[0];
        thisY= this[1];
        return x==thisX && y==thisY; 
    });
    if(filtered.length > 0){
       alert("yes"); 
    }
    else {
      alert("no");
    }
```

To test for range change the return condition like so:

```
return (x>thisX-0.5 && x<thisX+0.5) && (y>thisY-0.5 && y<thisY+0.5);
```

Comment: This seems to work best. How can I alter this to check if the values are within +/- 2 coordinate degrees? So if [1.5,2,0] is stored, then with +/- 0.5 [1.1, 1.8] would match?

Comment: You should not use `.filter()` in non-jQuery objects

Comment: Is there an alternative, Alex?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your fiddle, it appears the problem has to do with how JavaScript tests for equality -- two arrays of the same length with identical elements in the identical order are still not considered "strictly equal" (`===`).

To work around this, you'll have to [develop your own function for testing equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593590/how-to-detect-array-equality-in-javascript).