# Using array as selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a little trouble in jQuery.

```
$(document).on('change', '.filter-status, .filter-week', function() {
    var filter = [];
    filter.push({
        week: $('.filter-week').val(),
        status: $('.filter-status').val(),
    })

    //filter.week('week', $('.filter-week').val());
    filter.status = $('.filter-status').val();
    var tags = [];
    //console.log(filter);
    $.each(filter, function(index, value) {
        if (value != 'all') {
            tags.push(value);
        }
    });
});
```

I have a table row that looks as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is to hide a tr that does not contain tag 1234 and 1235.

#### Edit

To be a bit more clear.

The tags object contains id 1234 and 1235. I want to hide all table rows that do not have both these tags. So if a table row only has 1234 it should be hidden. If it has only 1235 it should be hidden as well. If it has both 1234 and 1235 it should NOT be hidden.

Comment: @Pete They are in the `tags` object as integers. I was thinking about imploding them using `join` but this is not possible because i need to surround them with data-tag=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hide any rows that have the same values as your tags array (I have added a class to your button column).

The compare function has been taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values)

```js
Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
    if (this.length != testArr.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].compare) { 
            if (!this[i].compare(testArr[i])) return false;
        }
        if (this[i] !== testArr[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var tags = [1234, 1235];  // example tags array
$('.button-holder').filter(function() {
    // put data attributes into an array
    var buttonsData = [];
    $(this).find('button.tag').each(function() {
        buttonsData.push(parseInt($(this).data('tag')));
    });
    
    return !tags.compare(buttonsData);  // compare the arrays
}).closest('tr').hide();  // hide the row if the values are not the same
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder"> <!-- add class to button column -->
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder">
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder">
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1236"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you are wanting to show all the rows that may have the tags values plus extras, you can use the following `containsAll` function instead of the compares function above:

```js
Array.prototype.containsAll = function(needles){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
     if($.inArray(needles[i], this) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var tags = [1234, 1235];
$('.button-holder').filter(function() {
    var buttonsData = [];
    $(this).find('button.tag').each(function() {
        buttonsData.push(parseInt($(this).data('tag')));
    });
    
    return !buttonsData.containsAll(tags);
}).closest('tr').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder">
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder">
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Some text...
    <td class="button-holder">
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
        <button class="tag" data-tag="1236"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, but I am looking for exactly the opposite. If a table row has both the tags it should be shown. Otherwise it should be hidden.

Comment: @Peter have a look at the snippets, the first only shows the table row with both tags in it, the second shows table rows with both tags in plus additional.  My comment may be misleading as I have put hide the rows if the values are the same (I forgot to change it when I edited to change  the filter the opposite way round)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()`:

```js
$('table tr').filter(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).find('button').eq(0).data('tag') != '1234' ||
    $(el).find('button').eq(1).data('tag') != '1235'
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Some text...</td>
    <td>
      <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
      <button class="tag" data-tag="1235"></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Some text...</td>
    <td>
      <button class="tag" data-tag="1234"></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works. However, the ids should be coming from my tags object. It could just as well be three or for ids with varying contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element and then go back with `parents()` to find the related `<tr>`:

```
$(':not([data-tag="1235"])').each(function() {
     $(this).parents('tr').hide();
});
```

Edited due comments that I misunderstanding the question:

> hide a tr that does **not** contain tag 1234 and 1235.

I missed the **not** when I read it

Comment: you should actually use `$(':not([data-tag="1235"])')`

Comment: Thanks. I figured that. What I want to do is to use the `tags` object to do this. So to be more clear: Hide all table rows that do not contain the tags in the tags object.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I misunderstanding the question to the opposite meaning. I edit that.