# how to check the array contains different values or same values in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

An array can contains multiple values. I want to check whether all the values are same or different.

> Example

```
var a = [2, 4, 7, 2, 8];   // all values are not same
var b = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2];   // all values are same
```

How can I check it in jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if two arrays have the same values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values), [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Comment: you can use underscore.js for the simplicity and use             _.difference([2, 4, 7, 2, 8], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
var a = [2, 4, 7, 2, 8];  
var b = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

    function myFunc(arr){
        var x= arr[0];
        return arr.every(function(item){
            return item=== x;
        });
    }

alert(myFunc(a));
alert(myFunc(b));
```

See the MDN for [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: I'd suggest a slight refinement: `return arr.slice(1).every(v => arr[0]);` on the grounds there's no need to check if `arr[0] === arr[0]`; but it's a micro-optimisation at best; and might not be an optimisation at all, if it takes longer to slice the array than it does to needlessly compare the first array element to itself.

Comment: Wow, great code, works fine. Thank you @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
function arrayUnique(array)
{
    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
         return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    var unique = array.filter( onlyUnique );

    return (unique.length == 1);
}   
// usage example:
var a = [2, 3, 2, 2, 2];
console.log('Array is unique : ' + arrayUnique(a)); 
// Array is unique : false

var b = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
console.log('Array is unique : ' + arrayUnique(b)); 
// Array is unique : true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using an array reduce:

```
Array.prototype.areAllTheSame = function() {
    if(!this.length)
        return false
    return this.reduce(function(p, c) {
        return [c, c==p[0] && p[1]]
    }, [this[0], true])[1]
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [2,2,2,2]

arr.areAllTheSame() //-->false
arr2.areAllTheSame() //-->true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using [**not**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function from Jquery

```
var test= $(a).not(b).length === 0;
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8u5awne/2/) example

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `Set`:

```js
var a = [2, 4, 7, 2, 8];
var b = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

function onlyOneValue(arr){
  return [...new Set(arr)].length < 2;
}

document.write(onlyOneValue(a) + '<br>');
document.write(onlyOneValue(b));
```