# How to check if one array has exactly the same elements as another (with duplicates) and in any order

Tags: arrays, swift, set

I tried using sets but obviously that doesn't work. I need a function to be able to work like this:

```
let Array1 = [2,2,1,1]
let Array2 = [2,1,2,1]
let Array3 = [2,2,2,1]
```

I need my function to be able to recognize that `Array1` and `Array2` are equal without thinking that `Array3` is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean?
Can you explain what you want to do instead of a function to resolve your issue?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions here, depending of the language.
Here is a complete topic on JS for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values

Comment: Basically I need the count of how many 1s or 2s there are in a given array