# Is it possible to use PropTypes to validate Dictionary-like objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I need to validate dictionary-like objects in my reducers, but since I'm already using Babel I don't want to resort to tools like Typescript.

Take this object as an example:

```
posts : {
    byId : {
        "post1" : {
            id : "post1",
            author : "user1",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]    
        },
        "post2" : {
            id : "post2",
            author : "user2",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]    
        }
    }
    allIds : ["post1", "post2"]
}
```

How could I express my expectations for the **byId** object using PropTypes? Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write custom proptype checkers if you can't achieve what you wan't with `PropTypes`' builtin proptypes.

If you want an all the values of the `byId` to be objects with the properties `id`, `author`, `body` and `comments`, you can use `shape`, `objectOf`, and `arrayOf`. If you want `allIds` to include all the keys of `byId` you can write a custom validator:

```
posts: PropTypes.shape({
  byId: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string,
    author: PropTypes.string,
    body: PropTypes.string,
    comments: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
  })),
  allIds(props, propName, componentName) {
    if(!Object.keys(props.byId).every(postID => props[propName].includes(postID))) {
      return new Error('allIds must include all the ids provided to byId!');
    }
  }
})
```

The above uses shape so it expects a `posts` object with the keys `byId` and `allIds`. It expects `byId` to be an object with the property *values* to also be object of a shape, with `id`, `author` and `body` being strings, with `comments` being an array of strings. Finally, it uses a custom proptype validator that checks if every key in `byId` (the post IDs) exists in `allIds`. If not, then throw an error. Beware though, this won't cover the case that `allIds` has post IDs that don't exist in `byIds`. See [How to know if two arrays have the same values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6229197/5647260) for more solutions. You can add `isRequired` where necessary.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being some kind of ignorant for asking this but, by putting `shape` directly inside of `objectOf`, wouldn't I be saying that one ,and only one,object of shape "post" is a direct descendant of the object "byId"?

Comment: @eddy I haven't tested it, but `objectOf` just checks for an object with *property values* of the type, in this case, a shaped object. It means *all property values must conform to the shape*.

Comment: What I can't wrap my head around is that by placing an object of an "X" shape inside the "byId" object , I will be implying that "byId" can contain **one or more** objects of that shape and that each of those objects will be a  key/value pair, where `value` happens to be of shape "X"

Comment: @eddy So `byId` is going to be an object with keys and values. `objectOf` defines that all values of that object have to be a certain proptype. The proptype for all the values of the object will be a shaped object with some properties. I'm not sure what your question is exactly.

Comment: I'm so sorry :'( .  I think my confusion came from my background in other languages (mainly strongly-typed ones) where to define a dictionary, you need to specify the data type for both, the key and the value.

Comment: @eddy `objectOf` assumes there will be keys of any type and the values the proptype you specify.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about the part of _keys of any type_ . Keys(property names) in javascript objects are mostly strings, right? . [The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) only says this : _"An object with property values of a certain type"_, and that was the part I didn't notice :S . There lies the key to understand that `objectOf` can hold one of more values of the provided type.

Comment: @eddy Yes, keys are mostly strings, and what I meant by 'keys of any type' I meant any type that was valid JavaScript, such as numbers or strings which post IDS can be. BTW have you tried the answer out?

Comment: Yep! Thank your for you patience and sorry for all the inconveniences. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @eddy No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score -2):

Using `PropTypes.shape()`

```
posts: PropTypes.shape({
    byId: PropTypes.sth() // could be shape() or sth else
}),
```