# What is the correct PropTypes for dictionary in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have something like

```
x = {"k0": [v0, v1], "k1":[v2]}
```

How should I write the correct proptypes for `x`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use PropTypes to validate Dictionary-like objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835973/is-it-possible-to-use-proptypes-to-validate-dictionary-like-objects)

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov That does not seem to answer my question. Could you double check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `PropTypes.shape` to specify an object that contains both `k0` and `k1` keys, and use `PropTypes.arrayOf` to make sure they are arrays of whatever type `v0`, `v1`, and `v2` are.

Some something like:

```
YourComponent.propTypes = {

  x: PropTypes.shape({
    k0: PropTypes.arrayOf(/* your type here, eg: PropTypes.number */),
    k1: PropTypes.arrayOf(/* other type here, eg: PropTypes.string */)
  })

}
```

Or, if you don't know the number or names of the keys beforehand, but they all have the same type, you can use `PropTypes.objectOf`. So to describe an object where every key maps to an array of strings:

```
x: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string))
```

You can read more about the available `PropTypes` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes).

Comment: Thanks! But what if I do not know how many keys I have in the dict? To be clear the types are always string to array of string but the number may be different.

Comment: In that case `PropTypes.objectOf(/* value type here */)` would specify an object that can have any number of keys, as long as the value for each key is whatever you specify. So for this, maybe `PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string))`

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Javascript are also known as Objects.

```
x: PropTypes.object
```

Comment: Yeah but I think object type is being forbidden by react recommended formatting (through eslint). From my guess it might be `objectOf(something)` but I am not sure what I should put here.