# Find a list of properties with duplicate array on the same object with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that has an unknown number of properties, the values of which are non-empty arrays e.g.

```js
const obj = {
  c1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  c2: ['a', 'c', 'b'],
  cx: ['a', 'b'],
  c3: ['d'],
  c4: ['d'],
  c5: ['e'],
  ...
}
```

I'm looking to find any duplicate properties, where the order of the array items isn't considered, and the result would let me know which properties match e.g. `[c1,c2]`, `[c3, c4]`

I can probably use a combination of `Object.entries`, nested `forEach`, sort the arrays before comparing.... but was thinking there may be some more concise approach with `lodash` that I haven't considered

Comment: What do you consider to be "duplicate"? Does it mean *full overlap* or just partial? E.g., if you had a `d: ["a", "b"]` would that be considered duplicate of `c1` and `c2`?

Comment: I updated the question to cover this - but no, in that case `d` wouldn't be considered a duplicate of `c1` or `c2`

Comment: Without lodash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230314/12057512. With lodash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817275/12057512

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to make sure I understood the question correctly. I also updated your title to represent the problem better, hope it is alright.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson note that the Lodash answer is not actually completely correct - checking with `["a", "b", "b", "c"]` and `["a", "c", "b"]` would report them as duplicate but the two arrays aren't because they have different number of `"b"`s. Same if the second one was `["a", "c", "c", "b"]` in that case you'd also get an empty result from `xor` but the two arrays aren't composed of the same elements.