# How to check the equality of two arrays with the same object properties but different sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to compare two `Arrays of object` and check the equality with the same properties but different sequences, for example

```
const array1 = [{id:1,name:'john'},{id:2,name:'wick'}];
const array2 = [{id:2,name:'wick'},{id:1,name:'john'}];

// How can I check if these arrays have the same objects
```

Comment: Why do you not sort them previously to check the equality?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/6229197/7785337

Comment: In my logic sorting is not required @ManuelMB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if two arrays have the same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values)

Comment: These two answers are for non object data, I need to work with object data

Comment: @ManirajMurugan but objects are non-primitive types so, it can't be sorted and compared like numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'wick'
}];
const array2 = [{
  id: 2,
  name: 'wick'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}];
const array3 = [{
  id: 2,
  name: 'abc'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}];


console.log('array1 matches array2? ', isMatched(array1, array2));

console.log('array3 matches array2? ',isMatched(array3, array2));

function isMatched(arr1, arr2) {
  //sort arrays
  arr1.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  arr2.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

  return arr1.every((obj, i) =>
        Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(arr2[i]).length &&
        Object.keys(obj).every(prop => obj[prop] === arr2[i][prop])
      )
    }
```

Comment: can you define this line // a.id - b.id

Comment: a & b refer to array elements (elements here are objects so, I try to sort them according to id property) .. same as sorting array of numbers  arr.sort((a, b)=> a-b)