# capturing on key press event using javaScript

Tags: javascript

in below example , **searchForward gets called when Shift key is pressed**
however **searchBackward never gets called when Shift + tab key is pressed.**
Please suggest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
      // var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (e.which == 9 ) {    
        var currentIndex = getCaret($(e.target).get(0))
        searchForward($(e.target), currentIndex);
        return false
        } 
        if (e.shiftkey) {
         var currentIndex = getCaret($(e.target).get(0))
        searchBackward($(e.target), currentIndex);
        return false 
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061084/detect-keypress-combination-series-with-javascript

Comment: if you're lazy like me http://craig.is/killing/mice

Answer (score 0):

On your second `if`, you are only checking for the shift key, not for shift and the key pressed. You need to put your second if loop inside the first. Also, I beleive you meant `shiftKey`, not `shiftkey`. JavaScript is case sensitive. Take a look at the updated snippet (also moved duplicate code outside the `if`): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GhpB/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
        var currentIndex = getCaret($(e.target).get(0))
        if (e.which == 9 ) {
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                searchBackward($(e.target), currentIndex);
            } else {
                searchForward($(e.target), currentIndex);
            }
            return false
        }
    });
});
```

Also see [JQuery or JavaScript: How determine if shift key being pressed while clicking anchor tag hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781142/jquery-or-javascript-how-determine-if-shift-key-being-pressed-while-clicking-an)