# Determine if the data is new before running (Compare an array with JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

Alright, I've got an interesting issue.  My page makes a JSON request every once in a while.  If the data hasn't changed, it doesn't need to do anything.  The problem is, I can't figure out a way to prove if it has changed or not.

I tried something like this to no avail:

var stations = null;

```
function parseDynamicData(ard) {
    //this was something that gave me problems for days
    //nice little hack to fix it
    if (ard['details']['enabled'] == 'true' && ard['song']['art'] != 'undefined');
    {
        //turns off the 'server offline' page
        if (document.location.toString().indexOf('#offline') != -1)
            document.location = '/#tracks';
        //update UI
        $('#track-title').html(htmlDecode(ard['song']['title']));
        $('#track-artist').html(htmlDecode(ard['song']['artist']));
        $('#track-album').html(htmlDecode(ard['song']['album']));
        $('#track-art').attr('src', htmlDecode(ard['song']['art']));
        //set if it's play or pause visible
        if (htmlDecode(ard['details']['playing']) == 'true') {
            $('#control-pauseplay').html('Pause');
            $('#control-pauseplay').attr('href', '/track?proc=2');
        } else {
            $('#control-pauseplay').html('Play');
            $('#control-pauseplay').attr('href', '/track?proc=3');
        }
        //Now update all of the stations
        if (stations == null || stations != ard['stations']) {
            $.each(ard['stations'], function (key, value) {
                alert(key);
            });
            stations = ard['stations'];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what a normal JSON response looks like:

```
{
    "song": {
        "art": "http://cont-sjl-1.pandora.com/images/public/amz/6/2/3/3/886978533326_500W_500H.jpg",
        "title": "Hold It Against Me",
        "artist": "Britney Spears",
        "album": "Femme Fatale Deluxe"
    },
    "details": {
        "playing": "true",
        "enabled": "true"
    },
    "stations": {
        "undefined": "False",
        "Alex Clare Radio": "False",
        "Rap Strength Training Radio": "False",
        "Drops Of Jupiter Radio": "False",
        "Tween Radio": "False",
        "Today's Hits Radio": "True"
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, however, it still goes through the JSON making an alert for every key.  Does anybody know what I should do?

Comment: I think some of your irrelevant code would be helpful for context... Off the top of my head, either stations is null (being overwritten elsewhere -- but that's easy to catch) or the `!=` comparator isn't doing what you think it's doing. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-javascript-array-equals or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: can you post the structure of your javascript object and JSON data? (i see no arrays in this code)

Comment: I suspect that `stations` and `ard['stations']` are different arrays that merely have the same values.

Comment: @apsillers if they have string keys they are objects, not arrays.

Comment: @jbabey Oh, true enough; I didn't have my critical thinking hat on.  Revised: they are different objects that merely have same key-value pairs.

Comment: I did an update to my post.  I added some more relevant information to help clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `stations` and `ard['stations']` are different objects that are identical in structure.  If you are rebuilding `ard` after each JSON request while `stations` holds the array from the *previous* `ard`, then the two objects are *not the same object*, so an exact match will fail, regardless whether the objects have identical key-value pairs.

What I would do is keep a *exact string copy* of the last JSON message and compare it with the current JSON string message before you parse it.  Otherwise, you'll need to compare every single key-value pair of the current object against the prospective new one -- and if some of those values are objects themselves, things could get a little (needlessly) hairy.

If you can be certain that the server will always stringify a given object *O* the same way (and assming you don't need to worry about checking if an object *on the client* has mutated), then you can simply compare the JSON string versions of the object from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using JSON.Stringify? Obviously what you get back from the JSON request is JSON, and I assume that you've converted the last request into an actual Object. So just call:

```
JSON.Stringify(Object) === JSONresult
```

and compare the two strings.

Comment: I wouldn't do that unless we can guarantee that the server-side JSON is formatted exactly the same as the stringified client-side JSON (e.g., same key ordering, no differing whitespace, etc).