# How do I test if one array is a subset of another?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What's the best (cleanest) way to provide this sort of logic?

```
var colors = ["red","white","blue"];

logic(colors,["red","green"]); //false
logic(colors,["red"]); //true
logic(colors,["red","purple"]); //false
logic(colors,["red","white"]); //true
logic(colors,["red","white","blue"]); //true
logic(colors,["red","white","blue","green"]); //false
logic(colors,["orange"]); //false
```

Possibly using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3115982/561731

Comment: Looks like he is trying to determine if the array given has only the elements of the `colors` array in it.

Comment: @MrZander precicley, thanks for being so eloquent.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming each element in the array is unique: Compare the length of `hand` with the length of the intersection of both arrays. If they are the same, all elements in `hand` are also in `colors`.

```
var result = (hand.length === _.intersection(hand, colors).length);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GXGun/)

Comment: Thanks, no matter how many times I read the underscore docs I can rarely think of these solutions when I need them.

Comment: as you say it's not working if the lements are not unique and it also doesn't work if you want to check the order: I created I gist to solve it with these needs: https://gist.github.com/timaschew/891632094c8bfcb73c38

Comment: _.difference(subset, superset).length === 0

Answer (score 22):

Maybe [difference](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) is what you are looking for:

```
_(hand).difference(colors).length === 0
```

Comment: It should be `_(hand).difference(colors).length === 0;`: http://jsfiddle.net/GXGun/1/ (you got it vice versa ;)). Nice solution though!

Comment: `return !_(hand).difference(colors).length`