# How to check if a string contains all the elements of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string `apple_mango_banana` and an array containing `[apple,mango]`.

I want to check if my string contains all of the elements present in the array, if so, I want to show a div with the same ID as my string.

Comment: please add your try and have a look here: [mcve].

Comment: post your code of what you have tried so far, what went wrong and what is the part that you need help with, SO isn't an code fabric that produces code for you.

Comment: Use split function to split your string in "_" .This will create a new array and then just check if your array is a subset of this new array.

This is how you check if an array is a subset of another array :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130104/how-do-i-test-if-one-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **[every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** function on the arr and [**includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on the str;
**Every** will return true if the passed function is true for all it's items.

```js
var str = 'apple_mango_banana';
var arr = ['apple','banana'];

var isEvery = arr.every(item => str.includes(item));

console.log(isEvery);
```

Comment: ie wont support, supports start from edge 14

Comment: `includes` and `every` are `ES6` features

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for such cases.

```js
var s = "apple_mango_banana";
var s1 = "apple_mago_banana";
var fruits = ["apple","mango"];

var allAvailable = fruits.every(function(fruit){
  return s.indexOf(fruit)>-1
});

var allAvailable1 = fruits.every(function(fruit){
  return s1.indexOf(fruit)>-1
});

console.log(allAvailable)
console.log(allAvailable1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string="ax_b_c_d";
var array=['b','c','ax','d'];

var arr=string.split("_");

if(array.sort().join("")==arr.sort().join("") && arr.length==array.length)
{
 console.log("match");
 }
```

Comment: This will not work if order is changed. Like `"banana_apple"`