# Javascript: checking if each value of array is included in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS function that creates an array based on the filters the user selects (this part works fine), and then I have another function (below) which loops through this array and should return true if the value is contained in the string and false if not.

```js
var testString = "winter casual";
var valArray = ["winter", "casual"];


function filterArray(...values){ 
  for (i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    if (testString.includes(values[i])){
      console.log(true);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
    }
  }

 filterArray(valArray);
```

However, I click 1 filter button to add "winter" to the values array and it returns "true", but then I click another to add casual and it returns false, even though casual is included in the string as well. I have console logged values[] to ensure that both "winter" and "casual" are in my array, and they are.

Comment: Can you give us an example that fails? aka, make the code above actually function with the error.

Comment: Are you passing an array into that function? If so you should not use `...` it should just be `function filterArray( values ) {`. If you call it as `filterArray('winter','casual')` you need the `...`, but if you call it as `filterArray(['winter','casual'])` you need to ***not*** have the `...`.

Comment: @Paulpro This works, thank you! Was going off documentation for ...values but I suppose I misunderstood.

Comment: This function does not return anything.  You might look at [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: @Brett `...values` creates an array called values from the function call's individual arguments. If an argument is an array that means you end up with a 2D array. You would have `values = [['winter','casual']];` which has only one element (so you were only seeing one logged value) and that element is an array. Then you end up calling `testString.includes(['winter','casual'])`. You would find that it would output true (once) if your string was `winter,casual` with a comma because the `toString()` of the array would match the entire `testString`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains all the elements of an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649681/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-all-the-elements-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `...values` with `values` as the parameter:

```js
var testString = "winter casual";

function filterArray(values){ 
  for (i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    if (testString.includes(values[i])){
      console.log(true);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
    }
  }
}
      
filterArray(['winter']);

filterArray(['winter', 'casual']);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Cannot upvote but you saved me from more headache.

Comment: You can mark it green to depict this was helpful to you. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, as your function doesn't actually return anything, but this is a fairly simple function that might be useful:

```js
const containsAll = (str, strs) => strs.every(s => str.includes(s))

console.log(containsAll("winter casual", ['winter'])) //=> true
console.log(containsAll("winter casual", ['winter', 'casual'])) //=> true
console.log(containsAll("winter casual", ['winter', 'casual', 'medium'])) //=> false
```