# How to check if an array of strings contains all elements of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings array1 , and array2 to compare.
How to check for the occurrence of all elements in strict accordance and create a new array.
I understand that in my case it is necessary to apply filter + includes.
I have seen the answer for [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649681/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-all-the-elements-of-an-array-in-javascript).

An example of what is required in my case and the expected result:

```
array1 [ 'apple_mango_banana', 'mango_apple_banana', 'apple_banana' ]
array2 [ 'apple', 'mango' ]

result ['apple_mango_banana', 'mango_apple_banana' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? I would suggest using loops before you go for the one-line-solution

Comment: i tried applying the filter using this example var is Every = arr.every(item => str.includes(item));

Comment: Please add quotes around strings and commas between array elements, so we can see what you're really trying to compare.

Comment: array1 [['apple_mango_banana'], ['mango_apple_banana'], ['apple_banana']]  array2 ['apple', 'mango']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array1 = [ 'apple_mango_banana', 'mango_apple_banana', 'apple_banana' ]
const array2 = [ 'apple', 'mango' ]

const goal = [ 'apple_mango_banana', 'mango_apple_banana' ]

let result = array1.filter(item1 => array2.every(item2 => item1.includes(item2)))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I originally wrote the array incorrectly, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You said array of strings but your code looks like an array of arrays of strings.
Assumining it's the latter, do you do it like this:

```js
let array = [['apple', 'mango', 'banana'], ['mango', 'apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'banana']]
let comp = ['apple', 'mango']
let ans = []

for (el of array) {
    if (comp.every(y => el.includes(y))) {
        ans.push(el)
    }
}

console.log(ans)
```

I'm sure you can find a one-liner but this way works.

Comment: A loop that just contains `if ... ans.push` is easily converted to `filter`.

Comment: guys can edit my answer if you want.