# How to compare one array with another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays as below:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,8,7,5,7,2,9,0];
var arr2 = [8,7,5];
```

I want to compare `arr2` with `arr1`, when it will find `arr2` exactly in the same sequence as it is then it should return `true`. i.e. if `[8,7,5]` is found exactly same sequence in `arr1` then it will return `true`.

**Note:**
We have to do this without using `indexOf`.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you know what a loop is and how to use it to iterate over an array?

Comment: Without code it looks like you didn't try at all?

Comment: @Dez: That doesn't take the order/sequence into account.

Comment: @Dez I don't think this is quite a duplicate, because this question asks about a subsequence, while that question asks about a subset.

Comment: This will answer your question (using difference/intersection):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130104/how-do-i-test-if-one-array-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: `arr1.join().includes(arr2.join())`

Comment: @Nicholas: If they can't use `.indexOf()`, they probably can't use a library. And that's a different task anyway. The OP isn't looking merely for an intersection.

Comment: @baao: `.includes()` is basically `.indexOf()`.

Comment: Showing what you've done so far helps demonstrate how much you currently understand and don't understand, which allows you to get an answer tailored to your current level of knowledge (and prevents endless back-and-forth of "well, I don't understand that answer, can you explain this more?" and "yes, I already knew all of that, but you skipped right over X which is what I really didn't understand..." etc)

Comment: @squint :D only basically :-)

Comment: I love when people ask us to do their homework.

Comment: In short, you loop through `arr1` - you check if the current item in `arr1` matches the first item in `arr2`, if it does you check the second item in `arr2` against the next item in `arr1` and so on until you reach the end of `arr2` (in which case you return true). If any items don't match, you move to the next item in `arr1` and start again at the beginning of `arr2`. If you run out of items in `arr1`, return false. So go ahead and give it a try and come back if and when you get stuck.

Comment: And with these answers, once again StackOverflow demonstrates itself to be the place that enables you to never actually have to think or learn.

Comment: @squint: Far from it. I don't think anybody has given the OP a complete answer they could actually use in their homework yet.

Comment: @epascarello But it is good, no? So if the guy doesn't want to do his homework himself, he gives us nice opportunity to practice our skills answering, making us better in what we do, at the same time making himself worser programmer than he could be. Se we have less competition and higher salaries! More bad programmers, isn't it good!?

Comment: @MattBurland: I don't know if this is homework or not, but I do see a complete solution below.

Comment: @dfsq The problem is people give them the answers, they are not learning. The way Stackoverflow is designed is not to lead people to solutions, but to give answers to problems. The issue here is person has no clue so they ask a question without showing what they attempt Some point hungry person charges in and gives a solution with zero explanation. This question is a simple looping problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 7, 2, 9, 0],
    array2 = [8, 7, 5],
    result = array1.some(function (a, i, aa) {
        return array2.every(function (b, j) {
            return aa[i + j] === b;
        });
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the largest array. On each iteration, compare the next values to all of the values found in the smaller array. If they all match, then it contains the smaller array.

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,8,7,5,7,2,9,0];
var arr2 = [8,7,5];

console.log(doesArrayContain(arr2, arr1));

function doesArrayContain(smallestArray, biggestArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < biggestArray.length; i++) {
     var doesMatch = true;
        
     for (var j = 0; j < smallestArray.length; j++) {
            if (biggestArray[i + j] !== smallestArray[j]) {
             doesMatch = false; break;
            }
        }
        
        if (doesMatch) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking whether one array is *contained* in the other, not if they are the same. I.e. the result for their example would be `true`.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right. Updating my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated :)