# Finding Sub-array within Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have the Array

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];
```

and I want to find the index of the sub array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So it should return the value 0
but every time I try to do this, it returns -1

Here is what i tried:

```
array.indexOf(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I know this is because the subarray i am searching for has commas in it.
how can i fix this

Comment: How exactly are you trying to get the index of that sub-array?

Comment: Would checking for e.g. the first element of each sub array be enough to you, or do you really need to check the whole thing?

Comment: @bfavaretto no, because some arrays start with same thing

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty solution which compares the arrays as strings:

```
var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];

var target = [9, 10, 11, 12].toString();
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   if(target === array[i].toString()) break;
}

if(i >= array.length) {
    console.log("not found");
} else {
    console.log("found at index " + i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMfwQ/

Comment: Very simple and should suffice for OP's case. +1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when javascript uses `==` to compare arrays it doesnt work as expected. You will have to build your own array equality checker (see [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-javascript-array-equals)). Then loop through the array and check per sub element if it is equal to the one you are trying to find

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || b == null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    // If you don't care about the order of the elements inside
    // the array, you should sort both arrays here.

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var haystack = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];
var needle = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var i = 0;

for(var sub in haystack) {
    if(array_equal(sub, needle)) { // found it
        return i;
    }
    i++;
}

if(i >= haystack.size) //didn't find it
    i = -1;

return i; //return the index of the found needle-array
```

Comment: Let me know if this works, I haven't tested it yet. Feel free to correct bugs when detected.

Answer (score 0):

a dead-simple string-matching implementation that uses only native methods and no variables:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
 .map( /./.test, RegExp( "^"+ [9, 10, 11, 12]+"$"  )).indexOf(true); // === 2
```