# removing item from array after match

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have

```
var a =[1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
var b = [2, 3]
```

Now I want to remove b from a using inArray

```
if($.inArray(b, a) === 1)
  a.remove(b);
```

is this right ? cause when i console a , it hasnt changed

Comment: Array doesn't have a method remove. You need to get the index of b and use splice. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array for details.

Comment: in your case `$.inArray(b, a)` will always be -1 because `b` is itself an array. you can't literally remove `b` from `a` because `b` isn't in `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this this may help you

```
function arr_diff(a1, a2)
{
  var a=[], diff=[];
  for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
    a[a1[i]]=true;
  for(var i=0;i<a2.length;i++)
    if(a[a2[i]]) delete a[a2[i]];
    else a[a2[i]]=true;
  for(var k in a)
    diff.push(k);
  return diff;
}
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var b = [2,3]
console.log(arr_diff(a,b));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors here.  First of all, jQuery's `inArray` searches for elements, not subArrays.  So you *might conceivably imagine* that you would find that

```
$.inArray([2, 3], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
```

would yield `1`, but in fact even that won't work, because it follows the `Array.prototype` standards and compares with reference equality.

It certainly won't find the array `[2, 3]` as an element of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Next, if it did happen to find that array, `Array.prototype` has no `remove` function.

You might want to look at **[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option (`arraysEqual()` borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436975/505154)):

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || b == null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

for (var i = 0; i <= a.length - b.length; i++) {
    var slice = a.slice(i, i + b.length);
    if (arraysEqual(slice, b)) {
        a.splice(i, b.length);
    }
}
```

This loops through `a` comparing slices of `a` to `b`, and removing that slice when a match is found.