# Javascript - arrays comparison

Tags: javascript

```
        var array1=[1,2,3];
        var array2=[1,2,3];
        alert((array1<array2)+(array1==array2)+(array1>array2));
```

As `alert` returns `0`, `array1` is not greater, not less and not equal to `array2`.
**The question is:**

*How does `array1` relates to `array2`?*

Edit: my question is: ***How does `array1` relates to `array2`?***

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators and the note about object references and equality.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040656/duplicate-distinct-and-unique-values-in-array-javascript/23040704#23040704) post, probably find something interesting

Answer (score 4):

The two array `array1` and `array2` are never equal as they are different instances.

If you want to compare them, you can do:

```
array1.join() == array2.join() // true
```

And BTW, the `alert()` doesn't alert `false` it alerts `0`

Answer (score 0):

Weird thing about arrays, they are never equal since they're not the same object.

Although, arrays act strange when you compare them with `<` or `>`

We can use this weird behavior to our advantage to check whether two arrays have the same content:

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) { return !(a < b || b < a); }
```

Or

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) { return !(a < b) && !(b < a); }
```

Which means, **if the no array is bigger than the other**, they're **equal**.

---

***Source***: [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-javascript-array-equals)

Comment: array1 is not greater, not less and not equal to array2

Comment: As I said, if the no array is bigger than the other, they're equal.
You are welcome to test the function I have given and check the results.