# Duplicate, Distinct and Unique values in Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have been using this [library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) in my google apps script, particually the Unique function.

So far this has done what I require, if I have two arrays like:

`[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,4]`, I have been using `array1.concat(array2)` and the using the unique function, which will return [1,2,3,4].

How can I retrieve unique values which in my example will be `[1,4]` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following function, it will return object of distinct, unique and repeated elements.

```
var a = [1,2,3], b = [2,3,4];
var c = a.concat(b);

function arrays( array ) {
    var distinct = [], unique = [], repeated = [], repeat = [];

    array.forEach(function(v,i,arr) {
        arr.splice(i,1);
        ( distinct.indexOf(v) === -1 ) ? distinct.push(v) : repeat.push(v);
        ( arr.indexOf(v) === -1 ) ? unique.push(v) : void 0;
        arr.splice(i,0,v);
    });

    repeat.forEach(function(v,i,arr) {
        ( repeated.indexOf(v) === -1 ) ? repeated.push(v) : void 0;
    });

    repeat = [];

    return {
        "distinct" : distinct,
        "unique"   : unique,
        "repeated" : repeated
    };
}

console.log(arrays(c));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qm5x/1/)

In your case you will get your desired result like `console.log(arrays(c).unique)` [1,4]

Comment: Now that is a lovely function :-) Thank you