# My == isn't working

Tags: javascript

I've tried everything. Hours later... I found out the basic == statement isn't working

Here's the code

```
console.log('The from1 section', from1.section);
console.log('The sender1 section', sender1.section);
if (from1.section == sender1.section) {
    console.log('It worked');
} else {
    console.log('They are not the same');
}
```

Here's the output

```
2015-02-01T02:19:46.371814+00:00 app[web.2]: They are not the same
2015-02-01T02:19:46.371652+00:00 app[web.2]: The from1 section ["54baf92d2b54840900dcb971"]
2015-02-01T02:19:46.371761+00:00 app[web.2]: The sender1 section ["54baf92d2b54840900dcb971"]
```

Comment: Two different array objects will **never** be `==` to each other. Object equality comparison is a comparison to see whether both expressions result in references to the same identical object. Two objects that look the same are still two distinct objects.

Comment: @Pointy You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Brad I was searching for a duplicate; there must be dozens but I haven't found a good one yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-javascript-array-equals