# Is there a total order on JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, comparison

The title pretty much says it all. Does JavaScript guarantee a total order on objects when using the `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` operators?

I wrote some code just to check total ordering on some objects. The result is consistent with total ordering, but that doesn't prove anything:

```javascript
function thereIsTotalOrder(items){

    var one, other, theThird;

    // warning: n^3 complexity follows

    // If a <= b and b <= a then a = b (antisymmetry);
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            one = items[i];
            other = items[j];
            if((one <= other) && (other <= one) && (one != other)){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // If a <= b and b <= c then a <= c (transitivity)
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<items.length; k++){
                one = items[i];
                other = items[j];
                theThird = items[k];
                if((one <= other) && (other <= theThird) && !(one <= theThird)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // a <= b or b <= a (totality). 
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            one = items[i];
            other = items[j];
            if(!((one <= other) || (other <= one))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function a(){};
function b(){};
var c = "foo";
var d = "bar";
var e = "bar";
var f = function(){};
var g = {name : "bananas"};

console.log(thereIsTotalOrder([a, b, c, d, e, f, g])); // prints "true"
```

Comment: JavaScript never guarantee any order on objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what objects we're considering. If we confine our attention to the class of [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), then yes, the order will be total. As your example demonstrates, the same can be said of (at least some) [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). But totality doesn't seem to hold generally.

For instance, if you add `var h = 5;` to your declarations and then add `h` to your `thereIsTotalOrder` call, you will get a `false`. That's because in a state where `h = 5` and `c = 'foo'`, (`h` ≤ `c` ∨ `c` ≤ `h`) is false (which means that [totality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) is not satisfied).

As you rightly noted, while the absence of a false value returned by `thereIsTotalOrder` doesn't *prove* that all objects  are totally ordered, the presence of a `false` value *does* prove that the order (if defined) between all objects is not total.