# Array.indexOf for list of lists is not working

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have a list of lists which comes from the server in `ajax response` has following structure:

```
var mapping = [     //response.mapping
    ["userOne", 1],
    ["userTwo", 2],
    ["userthree", 3],
    ["userfour", 4],

    ["personOne", 1],
    ["personTwo", 2],
    ["personOne", 3],
];
```

As the list will be constant forever, which will have only 7 elements at anytime. I want index of any of its element to update some DOM elements.

```
// Gives me any of list element which is random elm of the list `mapping`.
var captured_list_elm =  process_mapping_list();     
var status = mapping.indexOf(captured_list_elm);// getting always -1
```

Here I'm getting always `-1` for status.

- What could be the reason?
- Why indexOf can not calculate its index?
- What's the way to find it, get index through looping over list only?

Created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceham967/)

**NOTE** - Actually it should be a json but someone out of our team had written it as a list of lists. I can not update it as of now because the code is in production.

Comment: Show us: process_mapping_list.

Comment: @sirrocco - let me add a jsfiddle.

Comment: @sirrocco -Removed that function, I don't think that is required for demo. Have a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceham967/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) uses strict equality (`===`) to find an element. The elements of `mapping` are arrays and two distinct arrays that happen to have the same elements are not `===`. I suspect that `process_mapping_list()` is returning an array that *looks* like one of the elements of `mapping` but is not the element itself (just like your fiddle does).

You might need to write your own look-up function that uses a custom equality test. For such a test, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript). Depending on the environment(s) you are targeting, you may be able to use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of `indexOf()`. That function allows you to supply your own testing function.

Comment: @TedHopp- Okay, Thank you very much. perfect answer what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get around the `===` issue with indexOf...

**Option 1:**

- create a temporary array with stringified arrays inside of it and then compare the stringified value
- JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ceham967/1/

.

```
 var mapping = [     //response.mapping
    ["userOne", 1],
    ["userTwo", 2],
    ["userthree", 3],
    ["userfour", 4],

    ["personOne", 1],
    ["personTwo", 2],
    ["personOne", 3],
 ];

 var jsonMapping = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < mapping.length; i++) {
    jsonMapping.push(JSON.stringify(mapping[i]));
 }
 var captured_list_elm = ["personOne", 1];
 var status = jsonMapping.indexOf(JSON.stringify(captured_list_elm));
 alert("status= "+status);
```

**Option 2**

- For loop comparison
- JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ceham967/2/

.

```
var mapping = [     //response.mapping
    ["userOne", 1],
    ["userTwo", 2],
    ["userthree", 3],
    ["userfour", 4],

    ["personOne", 1],
    ["personTwo", 2],
    ["personOne", 3],
];
var findIndex = function (hayStack, needle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < hayStack.length; i++) {
        if(hayStack[i][0] === needle[0] && hayStack[i][1] === needle[1]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
var captured_list_elm = ["personOne", 1];
var status = findIndex(mapping, captured_list_elm);
alert("status= "+status);
```

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the answer @ted-hopp gave I forked your JSFiddle and [slightly modified](http://jsfiddle.net/xys180hj/) it. Basically what I did was to move the variable `captured_list_elm` to the top and add it as a value to the array. As you can see now Array.indexOf returns 4 which is the correct (zero-based) index:

```
var captured_list_elm = ["personOne", 1];

var mapping = [     //response.mapping
    ["userOne", 1],
    ["userTwo", 2],
    ["userthree", 3],
    ["userfour", 4],
    captured_list_elm,
    ["personTwo", 2],
    ["personOne", 3],
];

var status = mapping.indexOf(captured_list_elm);
alert("status= "+status);
```

What you probably have to do is to add a for loop that iterates over your array and compares the values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing two arrays using **indexOf**. If you run your jsFiddle with this code, it'll return the right index because it's comparing the array itself, not the elements within it.

```
var status = mapping.indexOf(mapping[6]);
```