# Javascript delete array element from array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an javascript array and I want to delete an element based on the value of the array, this is my array and this is what I have tried without success.

```
array = []
array.push (["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10])
index = array.indexOf(["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10])
array.splice(index, 1)
```

But it doesn't work, any idea¿?

Comment: `["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10] == ["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10]` returns `false`

Comment: is Mozilla and Firefox a variable name, or did you mean them to be strings? you're pushing an array onto an array, then searching for the array, which can't be done as suvroc poitned out

Comment: edited, they are strings, thanks

Comment: @aDoN And with the quotes, it works : http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/uoyx5L03/

Comment: it doesn't work for me, when dealing with an array of strings or numbers it does, but not with an array of arrays

Comment: @Magicprog.fr What you are seeing is an illusion - you are splicing the array backwards, since `indexOf` spits out `-1`. It's not actually finding that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare arrays, which are objects and have unique addresses. Your `index` variable is `-1`.

Try `['Mozilla','Firefox',1.10] === ['Mozilla','Firefox',1.10]` in your console, you'll see that just because two arrays have the same values, it doesn't mean they are the same array.

What you need is a deep-equals style of comparison, that checks each value in the array, to see if two arrays have a likeness.

Take a look at lodash's [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) function for an idea.

Here's a simple looping function:

```js
function deepIndex(array, comparison) {
  var i, j;
  
  main:
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] !== comparison[j]) {
          continue main;
        }
      }
      return i;
    }
  }
}

var arr = [];

arr.push('string', ['Mozilla','Firefox',1.10], 'thing');

var index = deepIndex(arr, ['Mozilla','Firefox',1.10])

console.log(index, arr);
arr.splice(index, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

This is function, made by the Creator of JQUery.
Basically you take the Index of one thing and than it is getting removed

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
      var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
      this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
      return this.push.apply(this, rest);
    };


//Equals Function taken from: 
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}   


array = [];
array.push (["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10]);
array.push (["Microsoft","Spartan",1.0]);
array.push (["Safari","Safari",1.4]);

index = indexOfArr(array,["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10]);
array.remove(index, index);
document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = array.length;

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("elems").innerHTML += "<br>"+array[i];
  }
  

function indexOfArr(hay, needle){
 for(var i = 0; i < hay.length; i++){
   if (hay[i].equals(needle)){
     return i;
   }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

```html
<span id = "length"></span><br>
<span id = "elems">Elements:</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fiter` metodh, instead of `indexOf`.

Within the callback of that method, you can choose different approaches:

- Use `toString` on the arrays and compare the two strings
- Test for the length and the content, by iterating over the contained elements
- ... Continue ...

In any case using `===` will solve the problem, unless the object contained is exactly the same against which you are trying to match.
By the same, I mean the same. We are non speaking about having the same content, but to be the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over your array and check the equality:

```
array = [];
array.push(["Mozilla", "Firefox", 1.10]);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (arraysEqual(array[i], ["Mozilla", "Firefox", 1.10])) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a === null || b === null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/r67jts35/

Based on this question : [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
array = []
array.push (["Mozilla","Firefox",1.10])
tempArray = array[0];
index = tempArray.indexOf("Mozilla","Firefox",1.10)
array.splice(index, 1)
```

You can build on this if you put `for` loop instead of hard coding.