# Testing for containment of one array in another JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web

I have a strange problem. I have a Javascript nested array and I would like to test for containment of an array in the nest:

```
var arr1, arr2;
arr1 = [[1, 2], [0, -1]];
arr2 = [1, 2];
if (arr1.indexOf(arr2) > -1)
   alert("success!");
```

However, the above code returns false for the containment test. Any efficient suggestions on the fix?

Comment: Going to have to loop and compare. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `arr1` is always an array of arrays, you can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to do this fairly efficiently.

```
var isContained = arr1.some(function(arr){
    return arr2.length == arr.length && 
        arr2.every(function(item,idx){
            return item == arr[idx];
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

To compare objects, you need to loop through the array as suggested by @epascarello in comments.