# How can I find the index of an element, in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a simple example of an array that contains at least one other array. I want a way to find the index of an array, within an array. However, the code I have below does not work:

```
var arr = [1,2,[1,2]];
console.log(arr.indexOf([1,2])); //-> -1

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == [1,2])
    return 'true' // does not return true
}
```

Intuitively, this should work but does not:

```
if ([1,2] == [1,2]) return 'true' // does not return true
```

Can someone explain why it does not work, and offer an alternative solution? Thanks!

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: in JS arrays are compared by **reference**. that's why `[1,2] != [1,2]`

Comment: The first `[1,2]` is not the same as the second `[1,2]`: they are different objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/710446)

Comment: In this case you can simply cast them to strings since the values are simply numbers: `arr[i].toString() === [1,2].toString()`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, this method will take too many resources for large arrays (it's just inefficient).

Comment: You could just store `[1,2]` in a variable first, assign into the array and then use `indexOf`. Although what this is actually saying is: *look for this array inside this other array* and not *look for an array that looks like this array inside this other array*

Comment: @DmitriySimushev As I've clearly stated I said *"In this case you can "*, the point being this is fine to use on small arrays with simple values. Despite in large cases iteration needs to be done completely on the arrays anyways, it's not going to be efficient regardless.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can check it yourself:

```
var a = [1,2], b = [1,2];

a.length === b.length && a.every(function(x,y) { return x === b[y]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are compared by reference not by value. That is why

```
console.log([1,2] == [1,2])
```

returns `false`.

You need a custom function that could compare arrays. If you want to check only the first level of nesting you can use this code:

```
var compareArrays = function(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the definitions of *similar* objects vs. *the same* object.  `Array.prototype.indexOf()` compares the objects using the [strict equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6). For (many) objects, this means an object reference comparison (i.e. the object's unique identifier, almost like its memory address).

In your example above, you are trying to treat two similar arrays as though they were the same array, and that's why it doesn't work. To do what you are trying to do, you need to use the *same* array. Like this:

```
var testArr = [1,2]; //a specific object with a specific reference
var arr = [1,2,testArr]; //the same array, not a different but similar array
console.log(arr.indexOf(testArr)); //returns 2
```

If you just want to know where arrays occur in the parent array, use `Array.isArray()`:

```
...
if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
    //do something
}
...
```

Hopefully that helps!