# why doesn't this code work for anagram checking?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split, anagram

I'm trying make an anagram check in javascript. For simplicity, assume that the function below only takes lowercase strings without any spacing/numbers/symbols. Why doesn't the code below work?

```
var anagram = function(string1, string2) {
    var string1array = string1.split('').sort();
    var string2array = string2.split('').sort();
    if (string1array == string2array) {
        console.log("they're anagrams");
    }
    else {
        console.log("they are not anagrams");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `==` does not work for `Array`, as `Array` is an `Object`. The `==` operator checks if the `Object`s are the SAME:

```js
var foo = {};
var bar = {};
console.log(foo == bar); // false
var foo2 = {};
var bar2 = foo2;
console.log(foo2 == bar2); // true
```

Thus, the *simplest* was to check this is to convert them back into `String` and use `==`, since `==` *does* work with `String`:

```js
var anagram = function(string1, string2) {
    var string1array = string1.split('').sort();
    var string2array = string2.split('').sort();
    // All I used was .join('') on both.
    if (string1array.join('') == string2array.join('')) {
        console.log("they're anagrams");
    }
    else {
        console.log("they are not anagrams");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare array elements directly like that in Javascript.

Here are multiple implementations that will do that: [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript).

In your case, you could simply use a `.join()` to compare two strings instead:

```
var anagram = function(string1, string2) {
    var string1_sorted = string1.split('').sort().join('');
    var string2_sorted = string2.split('').sort().join('');
    if (string1_sorted == string2_sorted) {
        console.log("they're anagrams");
    }
    else {
        console.log("they are not anagrams");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. did not realize that arrays can't be compared.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying make an anagram check in javascript.

**Well this is not exactly an Answer to this question but a different Approach to this Problem**; and in my first tests, way faster (33-50%).
Mr_Pouet and Andrew Templeton already gave you an answer to this exact question.

```
function anagram(a, b, caseSensitive){
    if(a.length !== b.length) return false;
    var c = caseSensitive? a: a.toLowerCase(), 
        d = caseSensitive? b: b.toLowerCase(),
        map = new Array(128),
        cc;

    for(var i = a.length; i--; ){
        cc = c.charCodeAt(i);
        map[cc] = (map[cc] || 0) + 1;

        cc = d.charCodeAt(i);
        map[cc] = (map[cc] || 0) - 1;
    }

    var i = map.length;
    if(i < 256){
        //faster for ANSI-like text
        while(i--) 
            if(i in map && map[i]) return false;
    }else{
        //faster for a huge sparse map, 
        //like UTF8 multibytes (Asian characters for example)
        for(var k in map)
            if(map[k]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```