# Immutable.Set.contains returns false

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I want to create an Immutable Set of paths. A path, in my case, is just an array of strings. So let's say we have the following paths.

```
var paths = [["a"], ["a", "b", "c"]];
```

I then create the Immutable Set like this

```
var selectedPaths = Immutable.Set(paths);
```

Although `selectedPaths.first()` returns `["a"]`, I cannot understand why `selectedPaths.contains(["a"])` returns `false`.

**EDIT**:
Well, I got an answer as to why this is happening, but I still cannot get it to work as I need it to.

**SOLUTION**: As @Alnitak has stated, I solved this by comparing a path to `Immutable.List(["a"])` instead of a simple array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set), Immutable uses the `Immutable.is()` function to perform equality checks, but that `.is()` check only performs "value comparison" checks when given other `Immutable.*` objects, and not native JS arrays, for which it performs a "reference comparison" check.

Therefore, try storing your inner values as an `Immutable.List` instead of as a plain JS array.

Comment: could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: Sorry - I don't have a suitable environment for testing `Immutable.js` code.  At a guess you'd have to use `Immutable.List(["a", "b", "c"])` anywhere that you'd previously have just used the plain inner array.

Comment: it is still returning `false`

Comment: I managed to solve it with your suggestion after all. Thanks!

Comment: @XeniaSis it may be useful if you include an update to show how?

Answer (score 0):

Testing two different arrays for equality this way doesn't work in Javascript, e.g.

```
["a"] == ["a"] // returns false
```

I'm guessing that the Immutable JS library does a simple equality check. Unfortunately, you will need to perform a more extensive check yourself.

Comment: so, what should I do to get the desired response?

Comment: See my edit - you'll need to perform your equality check manually. I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but if you want to reduce the set, you could run a filter operation and provide your own function to do the comparison. See this SO question that focuses on array equality checks in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript