# Why mapping an array using the same function return in different objects?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, equality

I want to know why v.map(...) is not equal to v.map(...) using the same function to do the map

```
var v = [1,2,3,4,5]
v.map(function(a) {return a+1}) === v.map(function(a) { return a+1;})
```

Running this on node repl, I've got the result of the second expression as false

Comment: Objects are compared by their identity rather than by their similarity. And, `.map()` returns a distinct instance of `Array`, with its own identity, every time you call it. [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: Also, perhaps, relevant: "[how to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)"

Answer (score 3):

When comparing the equality of non-primitives, Javascript checks equality by equality of reference - that is, do both objects being tested refer to the same object in memory?

In this case, they do not - `.map` returns a new object, and running `.map` on the same array two different times will return two different references - regardless of the computations done while mapping.

To sum it all up:

`v === v` is true because v refers to the same object in memory
`[1,2,3,4,5] === [1,2,3,4,5]` is false because both arrays are different objects in memory (i.e. reference is compared, not values)
`.map` will always return a new instance of an array - so the result cannot be equal to another `.map` statement

Answer (score 2):

This is because arrays are compared by reference, *not* by value, in Javascript.

In other words, doing something like

```
[1,2] === [1,2];
```

returns `false` in Javascript because the two arrays occupy different locations in memory. They are *not* compared by the actual contents they may have (which is what we would call comparison by value).

In contrast, doing

```
var x = [1,2];
x === x;
```

returns `true`. In this case, the variable `x` *refers* (resolves to the memory location of the array) to the same array and this common reference to a memory location is sufficient to yield `true`.

`map()` returns an array. Comparing two arrays by value is [a fairly complicated affair in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript).