# Is there a way to automatically check data equality for data type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.8

In `Python` you can do something like this

```
>>> a = ('a', 'b')
>>> b = ('a', 'b')
>>> a == b
True
```

However in `Typescript`

```
    type test = [string, string];

    var data1: test = ['a', 'b'];
    var data2: test = ['a', 'b'];

    console.log(data1 == data2);    // return false
    console.log(data1 === data2);   // return false
```

equality check for two data of the same type is using reference, I know I can loop through the array but are there syntactic sugar to check for data equality analogous to `Python` `tuple` ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. You'll have to resort to comparing each element of the array. I guess that's what TypeScript does for you in the background. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object comparison in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate as this is for Typescript which does automate a lot of stuff - but until / unless they add something like that, pointing at the Javascript answer will answer this

Comment: you can always add an `equals` method to the `Array` prototype which does this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to automatically check data equality for data type in Typescript?

No. The situation is the same as in JavaScript i.e. you need a library or custom code.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the right answer to this is almost always to use Lodash's [`_.isEqual` function](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual):

```
import _ = require("lodash");

type test = [string, string];

var data1: test = ['a', 'b'];
var data2: test = ['a', 'b'];

console.log(_.isEqual(data1, data2));
```

This will do deep equality comparisons for you, similarly to what you'd expect coming from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not ship this feature off-the-shelf, the situation is completely akin to that encountered in JavaScript: you'll need to recursively scan objects (I believe Python is doing something similar under the hood).

To achieve a quick makeshift comparison for testing purposes, you could convert your values to JSON strings, then compare those strings:

```
JSON.stringify(data1) == JSON.stringify(data2); // true
```