# Finding unique arrays in the most efficient method

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays,

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [2,3,4,5,6];
var c = [4,5,6,7,8];
var d = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

What is the most efficient way to find out the arrays that are distinct? I.e array a, b and c are distinct, where the order matters.

Comment: Where you say _"the order matters"_ do you mean that `a` and `d` are the same, but `var e = [5,4,3,2,1];` would be different, because the same content is in a different order?

Comment: try this very easy a.toString() === b.toString()

Comment: probably interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript

Comment: The solutions below are valid, a more efficient one would be to do something similar to bucket sort, but doubt you need that much efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every) to compare arrays with Javascript

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [2,3,4,5,6];

var is_same = (a.length == b.length) && a.every(function(element, index) {
return element === b[index]; 
});
```

Comment: only type-safe solution presented so far.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting way would be to convert them to String and Compare them. You could JSON `stringify` them or just `join` them like this

```
a.join('') === b.join('')
```

This works just because you say the order matters. I don't know the benchmarks between using JSON's stringify over join primitive. Maybe you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

This is also can be done like this

```
a.toString() === b.toString()
```

Comment: This works, unfortunately, I'm dealing with 20 MB JSON files and it's taking a long time.

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon that's something hard to do anything about then finding a way to make file shorter, it's not a good idea in best practice having a json file of 20 MB. please accept the answer if you find it useful :-)