# check array contains every elements of another array

Tags: javascript

How do i check each element of one array into another? here array2 contains each element of array1.

**code:**

```
function find(a, b) {
     var ai=0, bi=0;
  var result = [];

  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }

  if(JSON.stringify(a)==JSON.stringify(result)){
    return true;
  }else if(JSON.stringify(b)==JSON.stringify(result)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  // return result;

}

var array1 =  ["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Party Address", "Party Name", "Pincode"];
var array2 = ["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Name", "Party Address ", "Party Name", "Pincode"];

console.log(find(array1, array2)); //returns false
console.log(find(array2, array1)); // return false
```

Comment: Do you mean if valueN from array1 exists in array2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Comment: @PEPEGA, yes....

Comment: @Liam - Reinstate Monica, already tried but solution doesnot work

Comment: Well 251 people disagree with you

Comment: Check what once? There are literally hundreds of duplicates of this question. If you simply type your question into google you will get lots and lots of duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check **every** value one by one you can use `map` and `includes` to check if the array contains any value from array1

```js
var array1 = ["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Party Address", "Party Name", "Pincode"];
var array2 = ["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Name", "Party Address ", "Party Name", "Pincode"];

array1.map(x => console.log(array2.includes(x)))
```

Comment: `for`-solution that was previously accepted has performance advantage over that one as it will exit upon hitting missing element. Though you may benefit from both high order syntax conciseness and shortcut flexibility with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as it is done in my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160854/11299053) below.

Answer (score 2):

String contain white space in the end so make sure you `trim` it before process it.

ex: Party Address contain white space

```js
function isSuperset(set, subset) {
    for (var elem of subset) {
        if (!set.has(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


var array1 =  new Set(["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Party Address", "Party Name", "Pincode"].map(el => el.trim()));
var array2 = new Set(["Area", "Code", "Date", "Invoice Amt", "Invoice No", "Name", "Party Address ", "Party Name", "Pincode"].map(el => el.trim()));

let result = isSuperset(array2, array1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.includes()

```
const arr1 = [/* someValues */];
const arr2 = [/* someMoreValues */];

for (let value of arr1) {
    if (arr2.includes(value)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

you can also use `includes()` with `map()`

```
arr1.map(x => console.log(arr2.includes(x)));
```