# Array Comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array which i want to compare whether they are equal or not. Suppose array 1 is like

```js
let arr1 = [[null,""],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,""],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,""],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected "],["yes","Saved as Draft"],["no","File uploaded"]];

let arr2 = [[null,""],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],[null,""],[null,"File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],["yes","File uploaded"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,""],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,""],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],[null,"File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["","File Not Selected"],["yes","Saved as Draft"],["no","File uploaded"]];

if(arr1 == arr2) {alert("Yes")} else {alert("No")}
```

when i try to put condition `if(arr1==arr2){alert("yes")} else {alert("no")}`

it always return me No alert. But both the arrays are same.

Comment: 2 arrays are equal if all the values present in array are equal. If you are ok with this justification, then looping through each item and having a check would do.

Comment: Array variables are references (pointers) to the actual object, so two arrays will always be evaluated as different, unless you have 2 pointers to the same array, because you are not comparing their content, just their "pointers"

Comment: i tried with looping the array also with https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436975/2739391 this answer but again i'm getting No.