# looping inside an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, indexof

my problem is to update an array , containing objects , and each object contains array , i want to update the global array , with values refering to array inside objects , this logic !

`generalArray = [{name:String, features:String[]}]`

```
// Try edit message
let array1 = [{ name: "num", features: ['id']  },
            { name: "cat", features: ['gender'] }];
ob = {name:'num2', features:['id']};

function updateArr(arr,ob){

  const index = arr.findIndex(x => 
      ob.features.toString() === x.features.toString()
                              );
    if (index === -1) {
        arr.push(ob);
    } else {
        arr[index] = ob;
    }
}
console.log(array1);
updateArr(array1,ob);
console.log(array1);
```

this is working perfectly when features array of any object contains one string , but if it contains more than one string , exm features=['id','gender' ] it can't do anything ! help please and thanks

Comment: Please give examples of what you're expecting, it's not very clear.

Comment: i see logic determining if you you should push the object to the array. what is the desired result? Perhaps you can share share a few example inputs and what the outputs should be.

Comment: Looks like it works to me. Are you trying to add to one of the `features` arrays or to the `array1` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made a solution to your problem

```js
var array1 = [{ name: "num", features: ['id', 'gender']},
            { name: "cat", features: ['gender']}];
ob = {name:'num2', features:['id']};

function updateArr(arr, ob){
  for(var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(ob.features.join("") === arr[i].features.join("")) {
      arr[i] = ob;
      return;
    }
  }
  arr.push(ob);
}

updateArr(array1, ob);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: When order of the elements in the features array does not matter.

You can simply change the compare operator in your below line of code

```
ob.features.toString() === x.features.toString()
```

to

```
JSON.stringify(ob.features.sort()) === JSON.stringify(x.features.sort())
```

Option 2: If the order of the elements in the features array matter. Then you can simply remove `.sort()`.

Note: If you do not want to use `stringify`, then you can use the array compare function as mentioned in answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436975/989139.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = [{ name: "num", features: ['id']  },
            { name: "cat", features: ['gender'] }];
ob = {name:'num2', features:['id']};

function updateArr(arr,ob){

  const index = arr.findIndex(x => 
  ob.features.includes(x.features)
     // ob.features.toString() === x.features.toString()
                              );
                              debugger
    if (index === -1) {
        arr.push(ob);
    } else {
        arr[index] = ob;
    }
}
console.log(array1);
updateArr(array1,ob);
console.log(array1);
```