# TypeScript array of numbers is always sorted - even when it's not

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have made a function that checks whether an array of numbers is sorted:

```js
const isSorted = (values: number[]) => {
    return values === values.sort((a, b) => a - b);
};

isSorted([4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 10, 1, 5, 9, 6]); // Returns `true`
```

As you can see, the function returns `true` no matter what the input is, so how could I make the function work as it should?

I am using:

- TypeScript v4.1.2
- ts-node v9.0.0
- Node.js v14.15.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `values` with **itself**. Hence `true`.
You will have to manually check that each element on a given index in the sorted array is the same as each element from the `values` array on same index.
Something like this:

```
const isSorted = (values: number[]) => {
    let sorted = values.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)
    return isEqual(values, sorted);
};
```

`isEqual` could come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript). Answer by @Todd seems faster though indeed, but at least my answer shows some of the faults you had in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` method sorts elements of an array in-place and of course returns the original array.

You need to make a copy of the original array if you wish that it should stay unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check if any of the values are greater than the next value. That should be the fastest way to tell if it's sorted.

```
const isSorted = (values: number[]) => {
  let sorted = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
    if (values[i] > values[i+1]) {
      sorted = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample shared values getting compared with itself. In order to achieve desired you need to implement the sort manually.