# Redux: Is it common to do deep-compare at reducer and return original state if no change?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

- Action: fetch an array of data from the server.
- Reducer: save an array of data to store.

My reducer saves the array of data in the expected immutable fashion:

```
return {
  ...state,
  arrayOfData: fetchedArrayOfData,
};
```

The fetch action happens periodically, but the content of the array remains the same most of the time. However, since a new reference is saved each time, the selector for this data will be considered "changed", and doesn't memoize well if used as an input for `creatorSelector`.

The only solution I can think of is to perform a deep-compare at the reducer, and if the contents are the same, simply return the original state:

```
return state;
```

**If this common practice/pattern?**

*Note:  I tried to look around, and most projects are doing the same thing that I was doing (i.e. return new state object), which will do not memoize well and causes selector transformations to run.*

Comment: I do think that immutableJS can solve that by its nature. But I am not that sure as I am Angular dev

Comment: Have you checked redux dev tools and see action payload really deliver desired new content?

Comment: @AloisoGomes, do you mean if the fetched data was correct?  The fetched data is correct and is expected to be the same as previous fetch most of the time -- it only changes occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions like using [immutableJS](https://immutable-js.com/) as mentioned in the comments but you can return your state conditionally by comparing your `fetchedArrayOfData` with the last one (which is stored in your state).

Assume there is a comparison function that gives two arrays and compares them.

In the reducer:

```
const previousFetchedData = state.fetchedArrayOfData;
const newFetchedData = action.payload.fetchedArrayOfData;

const resultOfComparision = isSameArray(previousFetchedData, newFetchedData) // true or false

if (resultOfComparision) { // case of same arrays
  return state
} else { // case of different arrays
  ...state,
  arrayOfData: fetchedArrayOfData,
};
```

**Note 1:** you can create your own comparison function but there are many nice ones in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript/16430730) of StackOverflow which you can use them.

**Note 2:** using `immutableJs` and conditional returning data from reducer is common(in such scenario) and don't worry about using them.

**Note 3:** You can also compare your data at the component level by using the traditional way with `shouldComponentUpdate`.

**Node 4:** using middlewares like `redux-saga` will be useful, you can also implement the `isSameArray` function in the **saga** and then dispatch the proper action. read more on [saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) documentation.

**Note 5:** The best solution (in my thought) is to handle this case on the backend services with `304` status which means **Not modified**. then you can easily determine the right action according to the response status. more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) documentation.

Comment: On Note 2:  Ah, i didn't realize `immutableJs` actually returns the same `state` reference if there are no changes, so it is essentially doing a comparison each time.  I thought it will always return a new `state` reference.  The pattern was masked away when I peeked at other projects.  Thanks!