# Function to check number is palindrome not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've created this function to check whether a number is palindrome or not, but it's not working. It's pretty simple in fact, it will have to arrays which are the two halves of the number, the first one and the second one (reversed) and it will compare them.

```js
function luckyNumber(value) {
  let array  = String(value).split('');
  let array1 = array.slice(0, array.length / 2);
  let array2 = array.slice(array.length / 2, array.length);
  if (array2.length > array1.length) {
    array2.shift();
  }
  console.log(array1)
  console.log(array2.reverse())
  return array1 == array2.reverse();
}

console.log(luckyNumber(1234321));
```

I thought it was going to work alright, but when I printed both arrays and the final boolean in the end, it threw this:

```
[ '1', '2', '3' ]
[ '1', '2', '3' ]
false
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [JS Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), `.reverse()` happens in-place.

i.e. - when calling `.reverse()` the array is reversed in memory.
So, when logging the output of `array2.reverse()`, you're also (accidentally) reversing the actual 2nd half of the array. (so it becoms [1,2,3]).

Then, when comparing the two halves, you're reversing it again

> array1 == array2.reverse();

And if fact you're comparing [1,2,3] with [3,2,1].

So, reverse it only once.

**ALSO**

[Array equality is hard in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

```js
[1,2,3]==[1,2,3] // false
```

You could opt for:

```js
JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2);
```

or

```js
const isEqual = arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((value, index) => value === arr2[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array1` or `array2.reverse()` values are not about content of them,
but about their system address.

Change your array in string:

```js
function luckyNumber(value)
  {
  let 
    arr  = [...value.toString(10)]
  , str1 = arr.slice(0, arr.length / 2).join('')
  , str2 = arr.slice(arr.length / 2, arr.length).reverse().join('')
    ;
  if (str2.length > str1.length) 
    str2 = str2.slice(0,-1); 

  console.log( str1 , str2 )

  return str1 === str2;
  }

  console.log(luckyNumber(1234321));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare two arrays in that way, you can use this:

```
return JSON.stringify(array1) === JSON.stringify(array2);
```

But i did something similar time ago, i modified to your needs:

```
function luckyNumber(value) {
let stringNumber = String(value);


  let sizeStringNumber = stringNumber.length;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < sizeStringNumber / 2; i++){
      if(stringNumber[i] !== stringNumber[sizeStringNumber-1-i]){
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(luckyNumber(1234321));
console.log(luckyNumber(1234320));
console.log(luckyNumber(1234311));
console.log(luckyNumber(12344321));
```